# Returning a value from node js using express framework

Tags: android, node.js, express, twilio, voip

I am developing a android application for VOIP using the Twilio Api for android. I am using node js for the server.
The application is very simple,when a button is clicked I just need to retrieve a token which is generated on the server. The token is getting generated correctly.
But I am not being able to return it back in my android activity.

phone.java

```
    public void Initialized(){
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run(){
         try{
             String capToken=HttpHelper.httpGet("...../token");
            }
         }
      }).start();
  }
```

//Node.js

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var twilio=require('twilio');
var acctId='';
var authToken='';
var applicationId='';

app.get('/token',function(req,res){
var capability=new twilio.Capability(acctId,authToken);
capability.allowClientIncoming('dummy');
capability.allowClientOutgoing(applicationId);
var token=capability.generate();
console.log("token:"+token);
});
```

Comment: If that is your complete node script you are missing quite a few steps for running an express app. Checkout their [hello world](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html) example.

Comment: @jason..this is not my complete script,I have just given a part of it.:)

Answer (score 1):

Console.log will print a message to the terminal, it won't send a response. The function you're passing to app.get takes a request and a response parameter. You'll want to use the [response object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) for your response. See below:

```
app.get('/token', function(req, res) {
  var token = new Twilio.Capability(acctId, authToken)
    .allowClientIncoming('dummy')
    .allowClientOutgoing(applicationId)
    .generate();

  res.send({ token: token });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    app.get('/token',function(req,res){ 

        ...

        res.send({"token": token}) // <--- Should do the trick });
```